# Getting error `Type '{ theme: Theme; }' is not assignable to type` when trying to pass it as a prop to App component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm taking a slightly different approach as far as my app start is concerned because I want to use the `useLocation` hook in my `App` component. I'm a little new to Typescript, and I'm running into an issue. Here's what I have:

```
// index.tsx

const theme: Theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#43C099',
    },
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
          <Router>
            <App theme={theme} />
          </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
// App.tsx

interface IFC extends FC {
  theme: Theme
}

const App: FC<IFC> = ({ theme }) => {

// ...
```

The error comes from `index.tsx`, where my IDE underlines `<App ...` and throws the error,

`Type '{ theme: Theme; }' is not assignable to type 'IFC'.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It should be,

```
interface IFC {
  theme: Theme
}
```